# ¿Esta correcto este Truncate Table?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando un codigo para que al final del día me permita borrar todos los datos que se almacenan en ella, se borrarian de manera manual por medio de un truncate. Pero a la hora de ejecutar el php este no borra los datos. Falta alguna información (obviando la conexión).

```
<php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "********");
mysqli_select_db($link, "base_de_datos");
mysqli_query($link, "TRUNCATE TABLE tickets");
?>
```

Comment: La consulta es correcta. No obstante [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) dice lo siguiente: 1. Se necesita que el usuario tenga **privilegio `DROP`**; 2. Las operaciones de truncamiento no se pueden realizar si la sesión mantiene un **bloqueo de tabla activo**; 3. `TRUNCATE` falla para una tabla InnoDB **si hay restricciones FOREIGN KEY de otras tablas que hacen referencia a la tabla**. Se permiten restricciones de clave externa entre columnas de la misma tabla. ¿Has verificado todo eso?

Comment: En realidad no, soy bastante nuevo en el tema de mysql y php, revisare la documentación en busca de los temas que me comentas, muchas gracias!.